# Insert text to form text field and TOGGLE with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have managed to insert 'yes' into text field using jquery but I need to remove the text after clicking a second time. So: on click insert 'yes' then on another click remove text or toggle 'yes' and 'no'. it just adds yes, yes, yes.  I have spent hours on this and I am a noob

P.S: I have to do this instead of using a radio/checkbox because of a bug on marketing system.

```
<table>
<tr><td class="formCell"><input type="text" value="" id="text" style="width: 100%;" /></td></tr>
<!--BUTTON START-->
<tr><td class="formCell"><input type="button" name="yesOrNo"     class="checkBox" id="button"></td></tr>
<!--BUTTON END-->
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
$('#button').on('click', function () {
    var text = $('#text');
    text.val(text.val() + 'yes');    
});
});
</script>

Here's a jsfiddle:  
https://jsfiddle.net/k2exfu66/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a variable and change the value to create the toggle click effect. Then you can change the value based on this variable.

You just need to change your JS to:

```js
$(function () {
        var toggleState = 0;
    $('#button').on('click', function () {
        var text = $('#text');
        if (toggleState === 0) {
            text.val('yes');
          toggleState = 1;
        } else {
            text.val('');
          toggleState = 0;
        }   
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
<tr><td class="formCell"><input type="text" value="" id="text" style="width: 100%;" /></td></tr>
<!--BUTTON HERE-->
<tr><td class="formCell"><input type="button" name="yesOrNo" class="checkBox" id="button"></td></tr>
<!--BUTTON HERE-->
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is you want, forgive me if i understand wrongly

```
$('#button').on('click', function () {
  var text = $('#text');
  if(text.val() == 'yes'){
     text.val('no');
  }else{
     text.val('yes');
  }

});
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this is great

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery toggle function. You can get more info on this website: http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Your code should go something like this

```
$('#varName').toggle();
```

And in style add display none for that element so it's not visible at first load